# how to use xml comments within a method

Tags: xml, visual-studio, comments

I use xml comments in VS 2005 a lot but now I have a problem. I need to comment IFs, WHILEs, SELECT CASEs etc. But VS keeps telling me that it is impossible. Isn't there some workaround?

It would really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML comments are useful, because tools are able to read and understand them. So, for example, if you use a method in your code that has XML comments and hover over it, the IDE might tell you the `<summary>`. Or you could use them to generate a documentation website.

But none of this applies to inline comments. They are useful to you only if you are actually looking at the code in question, so there is no reason why tools should be able to understand them. And I don't know about any tools that do that.

But if you have some good reason to use XML comments inline (e.g. if you are using some custom documentation tool), there is nothing stopping you, it's still valid C#. But the compiler doesn't recognize such XML comments, so they won't be present in the XML file that is generated.